# Can I allow Mac using Internet Sharing via Thunderbolt to talk to other devices on network?

Tags: macos, network, thunderbolt, internet-sharing

Does my MacBook - which is connected via Thunderbolt bridge to an iMac with Internet Sharing - see devices on the network the iMac is connected to?

I can see a new subnet is created on the Thunderbolt bridge adapter: 192.168.2.x

My main network is 192.168.1.x - the iMac is connected to this on Ethernet adapter.

Can I let the MacBook connect to other devices on the 192.168.1.x subnet?
**I want to connect to a network share on another device in this upstream network.**

Ideally:

- I would be able to assign the MacBook with an (additional?) IP
  address in the 192.168.1.x range.
- Bonjour would be able to find
  devices on the upstream network that had file sharing enabled, and
  show them in the Finder sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling Inter Sharing on your iMac makes it a NAT router. Its main purpose is to connect the downstream networks (192.168.2.0/24) to other networks (like your main router connects your internal network(s) to the internet).

Your MacBook will connect to either other devices in the upstream network (192.168.1.0/24) or the Internet.

If you want to share a service on your MacBook (e.g. an Apache server) to the upstream network (192.168.1.0/24), you would have to forward the respective port on the iMac and add routes to the networks 192.168.2.0/24 on all other devices in the network 192.168.1.0/24.

Assigning an IP address of the 192.168.1.0/24 to the MacBook isn't possible.

Comment: Thank you @klanomath ; so you're saying I could connect from the MacBook to an upstream device on 192.168.1.0/24 without further setup? Using the setup in its default configuration, I was unable to "see" other devices on the upstream network for the purpose of mounting network shares; Bonjour service did not seem to pick up any of the machines and show them in the Finder sidebar. I wonder if this would be a matter of waiting? I have edited my question to add this in.

Comment: @robrecord Bonjour only works within a [broadcast domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_domain). Without additional tools/further config this is 192.168.2.0/24 for the MBP.